# Neo4j Get all nodes which related to list of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have database with labels :Theme and :Term. Terms related to themes. I need filter for terms by themes with AND feature. It`s will be like this: i`m choosing couple of themes, and geting terms with these all themes.
I`m sending ids of themes.

I`ve tryed this query:

```
MATCH (n:Term)-->(t:Theme)
WHERE id(t) IN [1, 2, 3]
RETURN n
```

But it`s **OR** logic. I need **AND** logic.

Comment: Do you mean you need all terms that belong to all specified themes?

Comment: @CleanBold Yes!

Comment: @CleanBold For example I have Term 'Function' in DB, which related to Themes 'Math', 'Programming', 'Biology'. I\`m sending ids of 'Math' and 'Biology', so i will get it. But if there aren\`t any of this themes in term, I don\`t have to get it. If I send ids of 'Math' and 'Literature', i won`t get term 'Function'.

Comment: This might help https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH [1,2,3] as inputThemes
MATCH (t:TERM)-->(th:THEME)
WHERE id(th) in inputThemes
WITH t, size(inputThemes) as inputCnt, COUNT(distinct th) as matchedCnt
WHERE inputCnt= matchedCnt
RETURN t
```

Comment: Would be cool if you could add some explanatory comments to your code snippet :)